# How to display time on buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, time, click

**Requirement:**
I have 2 buttons, I want when I click on button 1 its text should be replaced by the current time, and the same for button 2.

**Problem:**
The problem is when I click on button 1 its text change to the current time, but when I click on button 2 after a few minutes its text changes to the same time that button 1 has.

Here is my code:

```
 
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
     _getTime();
     
  }

  void _getTime() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    setState(() {
      getTime = formattedDateTime;
     print(getTime[0]);
    });
  }

var timeInText="Time in";
  var timeOutText="Time out";
\\button 1
RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeInText,
          bgcolor: Colors.blue[500],
          press:(){
            setState(() {
                          timeInText=getTime;
                        
                          
                        });

          })

//button 2

RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeoutText,
          bgcolor: Colors.blue[500],
          press:(){
            setState(() {
                          timeoutText=getTime;
                         
                        });

          })
```

please help to fix it. thanks

Comment: Where do you call `_getTime` function? And how do you store `timeInText`, `timeoutText` and `getTime` variables?

Comment: i call _getTime() on here , void  initState() {_getTime()  } and timeInText and timeoutText are variable initialized with "time in " and "time out"

Comment: let me edit the code

Comment: @kforjan please check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `_getTime()` only in `initState`. Time is stored on initialization and never updated after that. Since it's never updated it's showing the same time constantly.

To fix that add a `_getTime()` call to both of your onPressed functions like this:

```
onPressed: () {
  _getTime();
  setState(() {
    timeoutText = getTime;
  });
}),
```